# Did saying the Hebrew god's name outloud always call for a death sentence? (Deuteronomy 5:11)

Tags: untagged

Deuteronomy 5:11

> You shall not invoke [take] the name of the Lord, your God, in vain. For the
> Lord will not leave unpunished anyone who invokes his name in vain.

I have been studying about YHWH,the Hebrew deity, for some years now, but I am confused from time to time also! Did the Hebrew tribesmen (and women) always face a call for death, if they even accidentally spoke the name of their war god outloud!

Comment: This is not a Biblical question as nothing in the Bible prohibits this.  This question would be better for the Jewish site.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question belongs on the Jewish site.

Comment: It is generally agreed,that the Hebrews (around the time of exile) developed a superstition to not break one of the 10 commandments if I am not mistaken! To speak in vein,YHWH vocally, was strictly forbidden by the deity himself, and recorded into the Tora, now biblical text,as I understand this! Is this correct,or is my timeline off!

Comment: YHWH is the god of armies,,the tribal,patron war god ,demanding ,Ban, in many nations, so the Hebrews can take over lands of milk and honey! This is how the post seems biblical to me! The conquet naratives are a huge part of the OT narative,and the central character is always YAHWEH! He will not tolerate a vein vocalisation of his name!

Comment: That is just one of God's titles.  There are many more such as El-Roy, God of Justice, God of love, God of mercy, etc, etc.

Comment: Taking God's name in vain did not mean pronouncing it - that was the superstition that developed during the inter-testamental period.

Comment: I say it is biblical because YHWH denmands in the biblical texts,all hebrews of antiquity,to show regard and honor for his divine name! Granted ,the priests of the temple, even take this comand too far,and substitute with an eronious term,Adonai,in over 6,000 places,of what is now biblical text! Is this not  a textual ,issue of the texts!

Comment: How would one know what YHWH means to convey by that command! Evidentlly,  the ancients did feel he meant this ,could include vocilisation of any kind, and subtituted Adonia,as to not say the Holy name,even by mistake! 6000 times we still have the eronious word or title in our bibles today! That title is YAs title,substituted in English as LORD!

Comment: Even considering when the superstition developed, those of the YHWH cult, were using texts from a far earlier time period to develop the tradition we now call superstition! To them, it was just obeying their war deity, so more land could be conquered with his divine help!

Comment: There is no such law in the Bible.

Comment: You might want to edit your post to clarify how it pertains to understanding/interpreting a specific passage of the Bible. The post in its present state is likely to get closed as off-topic or migrated to sites such as HistorySE or JudaismSE.

Comment: This site allows Jewish approaches to scriptural interpretation. I will add the relevant quote in the hope of rescuing the question from being closed.

Comment: You will still need to quote a Bible verse that demands the death penalty for pronouncing God's name.  The passage now in your question is about taking that name in vain!!  That is very different from speaking it with respect.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is no. From the Talmud:

Yoma 39

> The High Priest mentions the name of God ten times on that day (Yom Kippur): Three
> times during the first confession; and three times during the second
> confession, over the bull; and three times when he confesses over the
> scapegoat to Azazel; and one time with the lots, when placing the lot
> for God upon the goat. And there already was an incident when the High
> Priest said the name of God and his voice was so strong that it was
> heard even in Jericho.

The prohibition against uttering God's name evolved at the end of the Second Temple period. It is rooted in the commandment not to take God's name in vain, which is related to the law against false swearing and Jesus' teaching not to swear at all. (Matthew 5:34) This developed into a strong tradition among orthodox Jews not speak the name of God. However, the Hebrew Bible is replete with expressions such as "As יְהֹוָ֖ה [yhwh] lives," and "I called on the name of the יְהֹוָ֖ה."(Judges 8:19, Ruth 3:13, 1 Samuel 14:39, Psalm 116:4, etc.)  Later, the Hebrew word יְהֹוָ֖ה  was replaced with terms such as *Adonai* and *Ha-Shem* - or The LORD in English. However, the text itself contains no prohibition against pronouncing the Name and it is virtually certain that priests, prophets, temple singers and the people generally did pronounce it. Indeed the Talmud (which is the source of the ban) states that this was once positively encouraged by the sages.

Berakhot 9:5

> The Mishna [the core of the Talmud] relates: ...When the Sadducees strayed and declared that there is
> but one world and there is no World-to-Come, the Sages instituted that
> at the conclusion of the blessing one recites: 'From everlasting to
> everlasting.' The Sages also instituted that one should greet another
> in the name of God, i.e., *one should mention God’s name* in his
> greeting.

Later tradition did indeed ban pronouncing the Name. However, there is no known case in Jewish history of a person being put to death for this. The [Jewish Encyclopedia](https://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/13483-shaddai) explains how pronouncing the name of God came to be seen as a crime in Jewish tradition:

> Forty years
> prior to the destruction of the Temple, the priests ceased to
> pronounce the Name (Yoma39b). From that time the pronunciation of the
> Name was prohibited. "Whoever pronounces the Name forfeits his portion
> in the future world" (Sanh. xi. 1)...

Maimonides would later write (Mishneh Torah, Laws of Oaths 12:11):

> It is not only a false oath that is forbidden. Instead, it is
> forbidden to mention even one of the names designated for G‑d in vain,
> even though one does not take an oath. For the verse commands us, saying:
> “To fear the glorious and awesome name.” Included in fearing [the name] is not to mention it in vain.

Regarding accidental utterances, Maimonides said:

> If because of a slip of the tongue, one mentions [G‑d’s] name in vain,
> he should immediately hurry to praise, glorify and venerate it, so
> that it will not have been mentioned in vain.

**Conclusion**: Pronouncing God's name did not always carry a death sentence. No such law exists in the Bible, and Talmudic tradition praises the High Priests who uttered it, as well a recalling a time when the Name was used in everyday greetings. There is no known case of the later Talmudic prohibition being enforced with capital punishment.

Comment: Moreover in Exodus 3:15 God says it is the name by which he is to be remembered, indicating it was to be used to refer to him.